# SQL Trigger or something else?

Tags: sql, database-trigger

How can I use trigger to update my table that have status column that is now set on `unknown`. How can I change this to "open" or "close" depending on the "time_spent" and "time_available" in the table? The status should change automatically when "time_spent"  =  "time_available".

Comment: Create a view instead. Or have a _computed column_.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? The 2 are very different RDBMS'. I have removed the conflicting tags, however, please retag the correct DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trigger. In fact, you don't even need to store this column. An easier approach would be to calculate it on the fly when you query the table:

```
SELECT *, CASE time_spent WHEN time_available THEN 'close' ELSE 'open' END
FROM   my_table
```